# C# Returning a Bitmap Width of 1

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

I am trying to create a bitmap and all I have is the savedUri and the imagePath.  I believe I am retrieving the imagePath correctly because when I go and look at the actual properties of the photos of the photo and the logged path they are the same so I believe it is a problem in the way I'm creating the bitmap.  Here is the code I use:

```
if (_bitmap == null)

{
    string imagePath = null;
    try
    {
        imagePath = GetRealPathFromURI(_saveUri);
        LogManager.Info("********the image path is", imagePath);
    }
    catch
    {
        imagePath = _saveUri.Path;
    }

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.InJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(imagePath, options);
    var width = (int)Math.Round(_outputX * 0.5);
    var heigth = (int)Math.Round(_outputY * 0.5);
    options.InSampleSize = BitmapTools.CalculateInSampleSize(options, width, width * heigth);
    options.InJustDecodeBounds = false;
    options.InDensity = 160;

    try
    {
        _bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(imagePath, options);
    }
    catch
    {
        GC.Collect();
        _bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(imagePath, options);
    }
}
if (_bitmap == null)
   LogManager.Info("********the bitmap width is:  ", "well bloody hell the bitmap is null");
else
   LogManager.Info("********the bitmap width is:  ", _bitmap.Width.ToString());
```

On the last two lines the bitmap is never null but it always has a width of 1 and when I display it there is no image.  This is for creating, displaying and saving an image on Monodroid but that isn't too relevant to this question as it is.

Comment: What value does `options.InSampleSize` get?

Comment: it gives me the value:  2147483647

Comment: OK, I think that's the problem.  `options.InSampleSize` is a scaling factor (if it is >1).  If it is 4 then the image is scaled to 1/4 of the original height and width.  In your case it is being scaled down to basically nothing, but I guess the minimum is 1 pixel wide.

Comment: wow that did it, just hard coded it at 10 and it looks great, I'll go back and see why that number is so large.  Thanks!